# Unwanted Automatic Git Merge

Tags: git

The file `WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx` is in my local repository and by error in the remote repository.

I put `*.licx in` `.gitignore` file.

When I use the command `git pull`, I get this message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

Aborting

I do a commit and I do this:

```
$ git rm --cached WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx
$ git --skip-worktree WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx
$ git --assume-unchanged WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

But the message is the same when I use `git pull`.

How can I use `git pull` without having to merge the `licenses.licx` files?

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated `.gitignore` locally ? If so you must check contents of the global gitignore file which sometimes influence your local gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

When you did `git reset --hard HEAD`, you undid the removal of the license file from the cache. Do `git rm --cached WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx` again, then do a `git commit`.

To be safe, make a backup copy of your local licenses.licx file before the next step.

When you do your next pull, you will get a merge conflict, since you have removed the file while at the same time someone else has obviously changed it (otherwise you would not be getting the original error). Resolve it using "mine" (or simply remove it from the cache again) and commit.

Note that this will remove the licenses.licx file on other people's machines when they do a `git pull`.

Comment: I do a 'git pull' for each line. For example:
$ git rm --cached WindowsFormsControlLibrary/Properties/licenses.licx
git pull

But every time I got the same message

Comment: @NorbertD - Do a `git commit` immediately after the `git rm --cached`, before the `git pull`.